# Como colocar uma imagem no json

Tags: json

Ola

eu estou tentando colocar dados no json uma imagem para depois no html aparecer um titulo uma localizaçao um texto e uma imagem, mas eu ja tentei url() e o src mas nao consigo por la isso...

```js
[
    {
        "titulo": "Exemplo",
        "localizacao": "Rua de Exemplo",
        "Texto": "Texto grande de exemplo para usar como teste",
        "imagem": ,
    }
]
```

o objectivo e aparecer assim no html

TITULO
localização
texto grande de exemplo
imagem

mas dentro de uma div, a minha unica duvida é saber se existe alguma forma de colocar uma imagem dentro do json pois vou usar o json como base de dados

Comment: sim, você pode ter no json o link da imagem ou os bytes da imagem, basta converter para `base64` que depois é simples de fazer o processo contrário e incluir na div

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso, você pode colocar a imagem em `base64`. Quando você escolhe uma imagem em um `<input type="file">`, você pode capturar a `base64` dela.

Comment: eu usei um conversor online para converter uma imagem em base64 mas fica bue grande o codigo da imagem e o vs code nao lê

Comment: Você tem algum tipo de formulário em sua página para o usuário passar as informações sobre titulo, localização, texto grande de exemplo e a imagem?

Comment: Eu já encontrei uma solução sem usar a base64 mas obrigada na mesma!

Answer (score 0):

Se você pode hospedar a imagem em algum lugar e passar a URL, é o melhor a fazer do ponto de vista de desempenho.
Base64 aumenta muito o payload e prejudica a fluidez da aplicação. Se não tiver jeito mesmo, use o Base64 como Natan sugeriu.